# Violation of foreign key constraint while copy-pasting features

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am building my first urban drainage model using GISwater, which connects QGIS and EPA-SWMM. I am using QGIS 2.18.15.

I have problems with copying and pasting elements from original conduits .shp layer to EPA SWMM DATA->Hydraulics->Arc->Conduits.

I receive next message:

```
Provider errors:
  PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  insert or update on table "inp_conduit" violates foreign key constraint "inp_conduit_arc_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (arc_id)=(406474) is not present in table "arc".
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO inp_conduit VALUES(NEW.arc_id,NEW.barrels,NEW.culvert,NEW.kentry,NEW.kexit,NEW.kavg,NEW.flap,NEW.q0,NEW.qmax, NEW.seepage)"
PL/pgSQL function ravbar.update_v_inp_edit_conduit() line 85 at SQL statement
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
Key (arc_id)=(406474) is not present in table "arc".
```

Don't know what you are doing exactly, but basically you can't insert a new row that has value `406474` for column `inp_conduit_arc_id_fkey` because that value does not exists in the table you're trying to reference. (Can't add child without mother).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/tutorial-fk.html